# Some mistakes I found after submission :(

Tags: thesis

1/I have already submitted my PhD thesis, and when I did rereading I found that 
1/ I forget to cite references ( 3 or 4 cite references)
Basically after writing some sentences I write this -> (cite something later ) at end of each sentence to cite a reference about that to remind me adding the references later, so I forget to add those references or even remove the (cite something later ) which will be easy to noticed , iam worried the examiners  will see that.. :(. .
2-Also in the experimental chemicals part I added by mistake some chemical names that I didnot use it and I’m worried about that too . 
3-Also two or three  figures number mistakes ) ..

Would that be considered as minor correction or major correction?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  You listed several issues, and you want to know whether each one is a major or minor correction?  According to what standard?  And don't you have the ability to correct your thesis after submission anyway?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I realize I made a huge mistake in my thesis and am not sure what to do. I'm defending very soon (days away). What should I do?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/87129/i-realize-i-made-a-huge-mistake-in-my-thesis-and-am-not-sure-what-to-do-im-def)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would that be considered as minor correction or major correction?

`It is clearly a minor error.`

Although those mistakes are more likely to be noticed and pointed out by the reviewers, they do not play an important factor in the evaluation of your dissertation.

It is a PhD thesis and not a 5th-grade report. I mean that your scientific contribution is the main criterion in the evaluation. Second, it comes to the overall writing style of the dissertation and whether it is easy to understand and does not contain a lot of mistakes.

Having fewer mistakes is completely normal, but if every page has a couple of them, this means that the author did not pay enough attention to provide a good quality manuscript.